# get the nested JSON Object value - Java SimpleJson

Tags: java, json

JSON:

```
{
    "issues":[
         {
             "id":"120171",
             "fields":{
                 "name":"Story",
                  "issuetype":{
                      "data":"inprogress"
                  }
             }
         },
         {
             "id":"1201",
             "fields":{
                 "name":"plot",
                 "issuetype":{
                     "data":"Unknown"
                 }
             }
     }]
}
```

I am using Simple JSON, I'm trying to pull id, name and data from the JSON array(issues).

```
JSONArray ja = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("issues");
for(int i=0;i<ja.size() ; i++){
    JSONObject tempJsonObj = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
    System.out.println(tempJsonObj.get("id").toString());
}
```

I'm able to pull the id value, how retire the data of name and data.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(JSON);
    JSONArray ja = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("issues");

    for(int i=0;i<ja.size() ; i++){
        JSONObject tempJsonObj = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
        System.out.println(String.format("ID: %s", tempJsonObj.get("id").toString()));

        JSONObject fields = (JSONObject) tempJsonObj.get("fields");
        JSONObject issuetype = (JSONObject) fields.get("issuetype");

        System.out.println(String.format("Name: %s", fields.get("name").toString()));
        System.out.println(String.format("Data: %s", issuetype.get("data").toString()));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ID: 120171
Name: Story
Data: inprogress
ID: 1201
Name: plot
Data: Unknown
```